# How to find my recovery version

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, nexus-4, clockworkmod-recovery

I am using CyanogenMod with CM-Recovery. my phone is encrypted. So I update my ROM using sideload.

But I want which version of recovery I am using.

Comment: Did you start recovery and look? Most recoveries show you quite clearly...

Answer (score 1):

installing something like [ROM Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&hl=en) might help.

check this screenshot: https://lh4.ggpht.com/mCWZ9q9niBabx-HBbrlez8hFxAh0VrhNl2y0_diCmxbmj93BF36nuPR_KcACgYXuXstd=h900-rw